# pass variable to thread

Tags: multithreading, rust

I'm searching a way to pass a variable url_path to this thread, as in this code:

```
async fn download_dist(all_paths: Vec<String>, mode: &str) {
    let mut download_path = "";
    let mut root_path = "";
    let mut url_path = String::new();

    if mode.contains("pool") {
        root_path = POOL_ROOT_PATH;
        url_path = format!("http://{}/{}", DEBIAN_REPOSITORY, DEBIAN_PATH);
        download_path = DEBIAN_POOL_PATH;
    } else {
        root_path = DIST_ROOT_PATH;
        url_path = format!("http://{}/{}/", DEBIAN_REPOSITORY, DEBIAN_DIST_PATH);
        download_path = DEBIAN_DIST_PATH;
    }

    let responses = futures::stream::iter(all_paths.into_iter().map(move |path| {
        tokio::spawn(async move {
            println!("{}", url_path);
        })
    }))
    .buffer_unordered(10)
    .collect::<Vec<_>>();
    responses.await;
}
```

Error is :
cannot move out of `url_path`, a captured variable in an `FnMut` closure
move out of `url_path` occurs here

Comment: don't declare it as `mut` or better create a copy in side of the async block

Comment: Once you're done mutating it, `let url_path = url_path`.

Comment: ```    
let url_path = url_path;

    let responses = futures::stream::iter(
        
        all_paths.into_iter().map(move | path | tokio::spawn( async move { 

            let url_path = url_path;
```
Same error

Answer (score 3):

`.map` calls the closure you provide many times.

The problem is that your `url_path` variable can only be moved to a thread once. So in order to move it to many threads (as you do), you have to `clone` it:

```rust
async fn download_dist(all_paths: Vec<String>, mode: &str) {
    let mut download_path = "";
    let mut root_path = "";
    let mut url_path = String::new();

    if mode.contains("pool") {
        root_path = POOL_ROOT_PATH;
        url_path = format!("http://{}/{}", DEBIAN_REPOSITORY, DEBIAN_PATH);
        download_path = DEBIAN_POOL_PATH;
    } else {
        root_path = DIST_ROOT_PATH;
        url_path = format!("http://{}/{}/", DEBIAN_REPOSITORY, DEBIAN_DIST_PATH);
        download_path = DEBIAN_DIST_PATH;
    }

    let responses = futures::stream::iter(all_paths.into_iter().map(move |path| {
        let url_path = url_path.clone();
        tokio::spawn(async move {
            println!("{}", url_path);
        })
    }))
    .buffer_unordered(10)
    .collect::<Vec<_>>();
    responses.await;
}
```

---

Side note:

If you set a variable exactly once before using it and the compiler understands that, you can skip the initialization and the `mut`, like so:

```rust
async fn download_dist(all_paths: Vec<String>, mode: &str) {
    let download_path;
    let root_path;
    let url_path;

    if mode.contains("pool") {
        root_path = POOL_ROOT_PATH;
        url_path = format!("http://{}/{}", DEBIAN_REPOSITORY, DEBIAN_PATH);
        download_path = DEBIAN_POOL_PATH;
    } else {
        root_path = DIST_ROOT_PATH;
        url_path = format!("http://{}/{}/", DEBIAN_REPOSITORY, DEBIAN_DIST_PATH);
        download_path = DEBIAN_DIST_PATH;
    }

    let responses = futures::stream::iter(all_paths.into_iter().map(move |path| {
        let url_path = url_path.clone();
        tokio::spawn(async move {
            println!("{}", url_path);
        })
    }))
    .buffer_unordered(10)
    .collect::<Vec<_>>();
    responses.await;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using `mut` but you don't need to. Consider:

```rust
let (download_path, url_path, root_path) = if mode.contains("pool")
{
    (
        POOL_ROOT_PATH,
        format!("http://{}/{}",DEBIAN_REPOSITORY,DEBIAN_PATH),
        DEBIAN_POOL_PATH
    )
}
else
{
    (
        POOL_ROOT_PATH,
        format!("http://{}/{}/",DEBIAN_REPOSITORY,DEBIAN_DIST_PATH),
        DEBIAN_POOL_PATH
    )
};
```

Collapsing it like this exposes that you're not really changing either `download_path` or `url_path` anyway.

> Tip: In Rust when you have `let mut x = ""` and then later assign to it, that's a sign you might want `let x = if (...) { }` instead.

If you're still stuck on the references, you can go down the `Arc` path:

```
  let url_path = Arc::new(url_path);

  let responses = futures::stream::iter(all_paths.into_iter().map(|path| {
        let url_path = url_path.clone();

        tokio::spawn(async move {
            println!("{}", url_path);
        })
    }))
```

This way each spawned task gets their "own" copy of the `url_path`, but to avoid needless copies, they're all `Arc` references to the same thing.

Comment: code is way better thanks :)
But error is same :/
Cannot move out of `url_path`, a captured variable in an `FnMut` closure
move out of `url_path` occurs here

Comment: You can `clone()` it before each call, or use the `Arc` approach shown in my edit.

Comment: If you use `Arc`, I recommend `Arc::clone(&url_path)` instead of `url_path.clone()`, as `.clone()` is ambiguous (could also be `String::clone`)